# Displaying markdown in EIN

Tags: spacemacs, markdown, ein

I've recently started working with EIN, and I have it mostly working now (sans autocompletion unfortunately...).

There's still something I'm struggling with which I'm not sure is even possible: is there a way to execute a markdown cell in a way that will display the formatted result like you would in the browser? I'm especially interested in latex and images being displayed properly.

Thanks!